# History.js onstatechange in IE7 does not work

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, history.js, onreadystatechange

I integrated History.js and this piece of code runs on URL change:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    var State = History.getState();
    alert(State.url)
    showPage(State.url);
});
```

It works well in all browsers except IE7 (compatibility mode of IE8). I thought History.js  would handle this.

Is it true that IE7 does not understand onStateChange event? What window event can be used for this case?

Answer (score 1):

From the notes on compatibility it states:

> MSIE 6 and 7 sometimes do not apply a hash even it was told to (requiring a second call to the apply function)
>
> https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Comment: Hmmm... that line in the documentation follows: "History.js solves the following browser bugs:"

If History.js solves for said list of HTML4 browser bugs, then this answer is cyclical and the opposite of correct, since it apparently still breaks in IE7 - right?